# Updating GeoLite2 CSV files

Tags: csv, geoip, maxmind, geoip2

Since 1.1.2020 one need to register with MaxMind to get access to the GeoLight2 databases.

I have just sucessfully installed the `geoipupdate` procedure and can update the GeoLite2 databases.

But I would need the CSV-versions - as those are the used by most of the tools I use.

I have tried to enter the ID's given in my account for the CSV-files, but this resulted in the following error message:

```
error retrieving updates: error retrieving filename: unexpected HTTP status code: 404 Not Found: Database edition not found
```

**My question:**

What is the simplest way to get the CSV-files automatically downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV-files are **not supported**!

As documented [here](https://github.com/maxmind/geoipupdate/blob/master/README.md#L6).

Answer (score 0):

date=20200107 works.
I guess they update every week\7 days

Comment: Have you tested the automated procedure with the CSV-files?

Comment: I download the zip version and extract the csv file

Comment: Geoipupdate is procedure with which you can download the databases. This can be run wit a cron job to download the required datasets. And yes I have downloaded the files manually and decompressed them. But I'd like to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a crontab every week to download the last update.

See here instructions for direct download:

1. Take the URL from Maxmind's site.
2. Replace `/geoip_download_by_token` with `/geoip_download`
3. Replace `token=XXXX` with `license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY`. You will need to replace the `YOUR_LICENSE_KEY` placeholder with an active license key associated with your MaxMind account.

https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/#Direct_Downloads

Comment: Have you tested the automated procedure with the CSV-files?

Comment: What do you mean by "automated procedure"?

Comment: Geoipupdate is procedure with which you can download the databases. This can be run wit a cron job to download the required datasets. And yes I have downloaded the files manually and decompressed them. But I'd like to automate this.

Comment: Yes I did it... what's the question?

Comment: When I specify the CSV-ID's I get the following error: "error retrieving updates: error retrieving filename: unexpected HTTP status code: 404 Not Found: Database edition not found". It works ok for the databases.

Comment: by the way: This is what I have specified in the ID line `EditionIDs GeoLite2-ASN-CSV GeoLite2-City-CSV GeoLite2-Country-CSV` which raises the error. The standard line `EditionIDs GeoLite2-ASN GeoLite2-City GeoLite2-Country`works fine.